# Multiplying and Dividing with BigDecimal and integer - Java

Tags: java, integer, bigdecimal, calculation

Is this the best way hoe to calculate BigDecimal with integer? It works as it is, but I'm thinking about best practice and should I handle possible exceptions.

```
    Integer salary = 120000;
    BigDecimal incomeRate = BigDecimal.valueOf(30.5).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    //Formula: salary * incomeRate/100
    BigDecimal taxableAmount = incomeRate.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(salary)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("Income: " + salary);
    System.out.println("Payable Tax: " + taxableAmount);
```

Result: 
Income: 120000
Payable Tax: 36600.00

Answer (score 0):

You should always use BigDecimal functions to do operations on Integer values.
Integer can be represented as BigDecimal but not always the opposite for example if tried to cast a BigDecimal to integer like this:

> myBigDecimal.intValueExact() it will throw an exception if you would lose information.

so Just do as you are doing and convert Integer to BigDecimal and not the opposite to insure nothing bad happens.

You can check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bigdecimal-biginteger) it has a lot of info on BigDecimal and BigInteger in Java.